# Flutter - VoidCallback called on null when adding 'await' in the same function

Tags: flutter, callback

I have a VoidCallback passed from widget to another, when called from second widget it functions normally, if i add an 'await' to another statement in the same function it breaks and shows "called on null" error

First widget:

```
  refreshLocalList() async {
    Logger.log("Refrishing list");
    setState(() {appointmentsList=AppointmentsController.getLocalList();});
  }
.
.
.
onTap: (){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => NewAppointment(time:times9to2[index],date: date,cameraId: cameraId.toString(),refreshLocalList: refreshLocalList,showInSnackBar: showInSnackBar,)));
                        },
```

Second widget:

```
    class NewAppointment extends StatefulWidget {
      final String time;
      final String date;
      final String cameraId;
      final VoidCallback refreshLocalList;
      final void Function(String msg) showInSnackBar;
      const NewAppointment({Key key, this.time, this.date,this.cameraId,this.refreshLocalList,this.showInSnackBar}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _NewAppointmentState createState() => _NewAppointmentState();
    }
class _NewAppointmentState extends State<NewAppointment> {
  Doctor doctor = Doctor();
  _NewAppointmentState();
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
.
.
.
child: Text("Submit",
                                ),
                                onPressed: () async {

                                  widget.refreshLocalList();
                                  Appointment newAppointmet = Appointment(doctor_id: DoctorsController.getDoctorIdByName(doctorNameController.text),
                                      date: widget.date,time: widget.time,description: descriptionFieldController.text,camera_id: widget.cameraId);
                                  AppointmentsController.addToLocalList(newAppointmet);
                                  await Queries.createAppointment(doctorNameController.text,widget.date,widget.time,descriptionFieldController.text,widget.cameraId);
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  widget.showInSnackBar("Appointment created");
                                }),
```

the call back is `refreshLocalList()`

the other call back `widget.showInSnackBar(String)` works fine in both cases.

if i remove "await" before `Queries.createAppointment`, everything works fine.

Error :

```
> I/flutter (14062): full doctors map size 57 E/flutter (14062):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null. E/flutter
> (14062): Receiver: null E/flutter (14062): Tried calling: call()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a theory: probably it works without `await` because `NewAppointment` gets a chance to pop away and your first widget becomes visible, so the `setState()` there works well.

However, when you `await`, it does not pop and first widget is not visible when `setState()` happens.

Try moving `Navigator.of(context).pop();` line before your await line

Comment: removed await and added your code, no exception was thrown, in the await-less case the "refreshLocalList()" works perfectly and does it job, by the way, the other call back "showInSnackBar" works even with await added

Comment: are you sure? you won't get an exception that stops the execution, you will see these printed in your logs. you can also set a breakpoint in one of these `print` lines and run it in debug mode to make sure that they are executed.

Comment: Yes, nothing was printed  on the console tab either

Comment: So i changed the declaration of the function from VoidCallback to Function and now it works, but if i remove ur code "catchError" it doesnt, i dont know whats happening ? when it works, it doesnt print " i was ignored" either,

Comment: Ok sorry now I took a better look at your code. Here's a theory: probably it works without `await` because `NewAppointment` gets a chance to pop away and your first widget becomes visible, so the `setState()` there works well. However, when you `await`, it does not pop and first widget is not visible when `setState()` happens. Try moving `Navigator.of(context).pop();` line before your await line.

Comment: Yup that was the problem, i had to move the "refreshLocalList" to before the await too, so its (pop > refresh > await) now it works, thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Ok let me place it in the answer and it would be nice if you accept it.